# If you are adding this ComposeView to an AppCompatActivity, make sure you are using AppCompat version 1.3+

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I got this error when I upgrade my compose version from `1.0.0-beta01` to `1.0.0-beta02`
(and also need to upgrade from kotlin-gradle-plugin from `1.4.30` to `1.4.31`.)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not set for this ComposeView. 
If you are adding this ComposeView to an AppCompatActivity, make sure you are using AppCompat version 1.3+. 
If you are adding this ComposeView to a Fragment, make sure you are using Fragment version 1.3+. 
For other cases, manually set owners on this view by using `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set()` and `ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set()`.
```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta02'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

My dependencies are as below

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

I did try to upgrade my `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` dependencies from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0, it will error stating `Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0.`.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this time, the latest AppCompat release is [AppCompat 1.3.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.3.0-beta01):

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
```

There is no stable version of AppCompat that supports the requirements that Compose needs as of yet.

Comment: updated version `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01`

Comment: im still getting this crash with androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01 and rc01

Comment: @Kochchy I'm stuck with the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ChiragMittal i avoid view-compose interoperability. Use just compose whenever posible. Rewrite ui to compose..